# RadioButtonList in Ember, Binding a model property to the selected value

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ember.js

I've reading and trying some codes but nothing has been working like I want i to... this is the code I have right now.

index.html:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="accommodation">3.2. ACCOMMODATION (*)</label> <br />
    <div>
        {{view Ember.RadioButton name="accommodation" valueBinding='accommodation' selectionBinding="isSelected" value="Not Required"}}
        Not Required 
    </div> <br />
    <div>
        {{view Ember.RadioButton name="accommodation" valueBinding='accommodation' selectionBinding="isSelected" value="Required"}}
        Required 
    </div> 
</div>
```

View radiobutton.js:

```
Ember.RadioButton = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: "input",
    type: "radio",
    attributeBindings: ["name", "type", "value", "checked:checked:"],
    click: function () {
        this.set("selection", this.$().val())
    },
    checked: function () {
        return this.get("value") == this.get("selection");

        if (this.get("selection") == "Required") {
            $('#panelAccommodation').style.display = "block";
        }

        if (this.get("selection") == "Not Required") {
            $('#panelAccommodation').style.display = "none";
        }

    }.property()
```

What I want from these RadioButtonLists is to be able to retrieve the value of the selected item so I can send it as a POST to a api and to use the selected value to hide/show a div dependidng on the selected value. Any ideas on how to do this?

EDIT:

I'm trying andrusieczko's code and so far I have this:

radio.js :

```
App.RadioView = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: 'input',
    type: 'radio',
    attributeBindings: ['type', 'htmlChecked:checked', 'value', 'name'],

    htmlChecked: function () {
        return this.get('value') === this.get('checked');
    }.property('value', 'checked'),

    change: function () {
        this.set('checked', this.get('value'));
    },

    _updateElementValue: function () {
        Ember.run.next(this, function () {
            this.$().prop('checked', this.get('htmlChecked'));
        });
    }.observes('htmlChecked')
});

Ember.Handlebars.helper('radio-button', App.RadioView);
```

controller:

```
App.EventsNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

    acRequired: 'Required',
    acNotRequired: 'Not Required',

    accommodation: null,
```

Index.html :

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="accommodation">3.2. ACCOMMODATION (*)</label> <br />
     <div>
         {{radio-button value=acRequired checked=accommodation}}
         Not Required 
     </div>
     <div>
         {{radio-button value=acNotRequired checked=accommodation}}
         Required 
     </div> 
</div>
```

still not sending the selected value on the POST request.

EDIT 2:

I've written some code that in all others aspects is behaving like I want it to but it's still not binding the selected value to the property I want it to.

View radio.js:

```
Ember.Radio = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: "input",
    type: "radio",
    attributeBindings: ["name", "type", "value", "checked:checked:"],
    click: function () {
        this.set("selection", this.$().val())

        if(this.get("selection") === "acRequired") {
            $('#panelAccommodation').css("display", "block");
            this.set("selection", "Required");
            selectionBinding: "App.event.accommodation"
        }
        if (this.get("selection") === "acNotRequired") {
            $('#panelAccommodation').css("display", "none");
            this.set("selection", "Not Required");
            selectionBinding: "App.event.accommodation"
        }
        if (this.get("selection") === "flRequired") {
            $('#panelFlight').css("display", "block");
            this.set("selection", "Required");
            selectionBinding: "App.event.flight"
        }
        if (this.get("selection") === "flNotRequired") {
            $('#panelFlight').css("display", "none");
            this.set("selection", "Not Required");
            selectionBinding: "App.event.flight"
        }
    },

    checked: function () {
        return this.get("value") == this.get("selection");
    }.property()
});
```

Index.html :

```
    <!-- Accommodation - RadioButtonList -->
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="accommodation">3.2. ACCOMMODATION (*)</label> <br />
     <div>
          {{view Ember.Radio name="accommodation" selectionBinding='accommodation' value="acNotRequired"}}
          Not Required
     </div>
     <div>
          {{view Ember.Radio name="accommodation" selectionBinding='accommodation' value="acRequired"}}
          Required
     </div>
</div>
```

controller new.js :

```
App.EventsNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

    accommodation: "Not Required",
    flight: "Not Required",

    actions: {
        save: function () {
            var self = this;
            this.get('model').set('status', 'Created');
            this.get('model').save().then(function () {
                self.transitionToRoute('events.table');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

PS: I'm using Ember version 1.6.1

Comment: I've made several changes to the code but there's still something I have doubts about, should I do another edit (the question will be really long!), just erase the content of the question and replace it (might get confusing for future visitors) or start another question on the same topic?

Comment: hey, you're first EDIT looks fine; how do you send the POST request in the controller? do you use `accommodation` property in it?

Comment: I've added my controller for a post in the end but this isn't working... when I do something like {{accommodaiton}} in the form it's reading the value correctly and changing as I change it but when the form is submited the POST request has accommodaiton as null always

Comment: Where is your `model` in the first place? is it created / found in your `Route`? moreover, `accomodation` is not bound to your model. What you probably wanted to do is to have ` {{radio-button value=acRequired checked=model.accommodation}}` in your hbs file. Then, `accomodation` property will be changed in the `model`. Of course assuming that `this.get('model')` is an existing model.

Comment: I got it to work!!! thanks to you man, thanks a lot really! I was struggling with this for a while, you saved me ;)!

Comment: Hey, I just saw your comment... :) I've created a repo for you with the whole example working: https://github.com/andrusieczko/radiobutton-example.git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using either Ember App Kit or ember-cli, then all you have to do is:

```
App.RadioView = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: 'input',
  type: 'radio',
  attributeBindings: ['type', 'htmlChecked:checked', 'value', 'name'],

  htmlChecked: function() {
    return this.get('value') === this.get('checked');
  }.property('value', 'checked'),

  change: function() {
    this.set('checked', this.get('value'));
  },

  _updateElementValue: function() {
    Ember.run.next(this, function() {
      this.$().prop('checked', this.get('htmlChecked'));
    });
  }.observes('htmlChecked')
});

Ember.Handlebars.helper('radio-button', App.RadioView);
```

Then, in your Controller:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  country1: 'USA',
  country2: 'Singapore',
  country3: 'Poland',

  country: null,
});
```

and in your template:

```
{{radio-button value=country1 checked=country}}
{{radio-button value=country2 checked=country}}
{{radio-button value=country3 checked=country}}
```

and you can listen to the properties you passed to the helper and based on that trigger other actions.

And it can be easily used along with `{{each}}` :)

Does it help?

**The working example (Ember 1.6.1, ember-data 1.0.0-beta.9)**:
https://github.com/andrusieczko/radiobutton-example.git

Disclaimer: I'm not the author of the code, I took it from somewhere some time ago.

Comment: ah, right, you're not using EAK of ember-cli... my bad... I've got limited time now but instead of `export default`, use the Ember's convention: `App.RadioView = ` and probably same for the helper. And the line in the helper would be `Ember.Handlebars.makeViewHelper(App.RadioView)`

Comment: If you can please edit your anwer when you have time. Sorry and thanks .

Answer (score 0):

If you can handle not using HTML `<input>` elements, try using this component that I wrote.

Note that I'm using Ember 1.10 and Ember-CLI.

`my-template.js` (controller)

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({

    options: [Ember.Object.create({
        name: "Required",
        value: "1",
    }), Ember.Object.create({
        name: "Not Required",
        value: "0",
    })],

    actions: {
        optionChanged: function(option) {
            // option.value will either be 1 or 0 in this case.
        }
    }
});
```

`my-template.hbs`

```
{{#mutex-button-set key="value" default=options.firstObject stateChanged="optionChanged" buttons=options as |button|}}
    <div>{{button.name}}</div>
{{/mutex-button-set}}
```

`mutex-button-set.hbs`

```
{{#each button in buttons}}
    <div {{bind-attr class=":mutex-button button.selected:selected"}} {{action "setSelected" button}}>
        {{yield button}}
    </div>  
{{/each}}
```

`mutex-button-set.js`

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    classNames: ['mutex-button-set'],

    actions: {
        setSelected: function(obj) {
            var key = this.get("key");

            this.get("buttons").forEach(function(button) {
                Ember.set(button, "selected", obj && (button.get(key) === obj.get(key)));
            });

            if (obj) {
                this.sendAction('stateChanged', obj);   
            }
        }
    },

    didInsertElement: function() {
        this.send("setSelected", this.get("default"));
    }

});
```

HTML Generated

```
<div id="ember554" class="ember-view mutex-button-set">
    <div data-ember-action="559" class="mutex-button selected">
        <div>Required</div>
    </div>  
    <div data-ember-action="563" class="mutex-button ">
        <div>Not Required</div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: I'm using Ember 1.6.1 and I'm not using Ember-CLI

Comment: That was 6 releases ago. Start migrating now so you're ready for Ember 2.0.  :)

Comment: I have to do this project in this version but the next ones I'll definetely use more recent versions :)